# Flutter disable and enable buttons

Tags: flutter, dart

i had made a function that enabled the second button when i press the first one, everything is working fine but when the second button is enabled i want to go to another page when i press on the second one but i can t do that, how can I reach that. Here is my code:

```
  child: MaterialButton(
                    elevation: 0,
                    // ignore: avoid_returning_null_for_void
                    onPressed: isDisable ? () => null : clickButton(),
                    child: Text(
                      'Done',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.sp, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                  ),
```

I want here on pressed to go to another page but i cant in this form how can i reach that? Thank in advance

I've tried with setState

Answer (score 0):

You like provide null directly instead of method body. Use like.

```dart
 onPressed: isDisable ? null:() => clickButton(),
```

Or can be

```dart
 onPressed: isDisable ? null: clickButton, //depend on `clickButton`
```

This way, you will be able to see the disable state on ui.

Comment: void clickButton() {
    isDisable = false;
  }

Comment: you like to navigate on different route/page? try `void clickButton() {
    isDisable = false;
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => YourPage(),
    ));
  }`

Comment: Nah, it s not working like that, any advice?

Comment: Try to add print state inside function to check if it is working. Can you include two sample widgets that will reproduce the issue.

Comment: FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building.

Comment: This is the error that i get

Comment: I think you added `()` directly, is there other places you are calling setState inside method like this. for question snippet it should be `onPressed: isDisable ? null:() => clickButton()`